# GLOBAL_AGENT.HTTP_PROXY not letting me build Electron Pacakge

Tags: npm, electron, electron-packager

**the problem**

```
npm init -y
npm i path electron request http
npx electron-packager . --arch=ia32 --platform=win32 --out=release --electron-version=13.1.9
```

to build an electron project found in the current directory. Previous to reformatting my OS, I never had issues with this. However, now every time I execute these commands, after the last one `electron-packager`.

**the error**

In the console, I see `Unsupported GLOBAL_AGENT.HTTP_PROXY configuration value: URL protocol must be "http:"`

I cannot find any help on Google, or Stackoverflow about why this is occurring.

**what i tried**

I tried commenting out all parts of code in my relatively small project, to try to figure out what is giving me this issue.

I also tried repackaging the same project on my MacOS & Windows 10/11 machines, nothing works.

I am really frustrated/confused as to why this is happening, especially since I was able to use `electron-packager` a while back on the exact same project with no issues.

**project dependencies**

```
http@0.0.1-security
electron@17.1.2
request@2.88.2
path@0.12.7
```

Comment: Will tip someone $50 in BTC for help with this issue

Comment: Any info in the error message as to where the error is thrown? Please [edit] your question and include the complete stack trace as well as the version numbers of all of your dependencies. Also, the currency of Stack Overflow is reputation -- if you have enough of it, you will eventually be able to post bounties for your questions. In the meantime, be patient and give us as much information as is needed to solve this problem. In your case however, it may not even be related to your project but to its dependencies.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner The error is thrown when I execute `npx electron-packager . --arch=ia32 --platform=win32 --out=release --electron-version=13.1.9` from cmd.exe, it is the only error produced by the output from that command. Added project dependencies to the question.

Comment: having the same issue here with `electron-forge` not able to package the latest installer

Comment: @Jonathan Thank goodness its not just me, I was so frustrated by this! I am now using `electron-builder` with `npx electron-builder --windows --ia32` as an alternative, it seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is a bug, has been fixed 5 hours ago (Mar 14, 2022, 9:55 PM GMT)

[GLOBAL_AGENT.HTTP_PROXY configuration value: URL protocol must be http](https://github.com/electron/get/issues/215)

Just do:

```
npm update
```