# Unsupported `GLOBAL_AGENT.HTTP_PROXY` configuration value: URL protocol must be "http:" when running electron-packager

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-packager

I was trying to package an Electron applicationusing electron-packager but get this error:

```
Unsupported `GLOBAL_AGENT.HTTP_PROXY` configuration value: URL protocol must be "http:".
```

The command that I ran is:

```
npx electron-packager . dodge-them-all --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --prune=true --out=bin
```

and expected for it to create a folder with the executable file, but got an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GLOBAL\_AGENT.HTTP\_PROXY not letting me build Electron Pacakge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71462161/global-agent-http-proxy-not-letting-me-build-electron-pacakge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [GLOBAL_AGENT.HTTP_PROXY not letting me build Electron Pacakge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71462161/global-agent-http-proxy-not-letting-me-build-electron-pacakge)
All you need to do is: `npm update`

Comment: your welcome! glad i could help!

Comment: I also had the same problem